# Receiving Proxy error: Error occurred while proxying request [ECONNREFUSED] in react app

Tags: android, node.js, reactjs, react-native, api

I have a react application that is making API calls through `axios` to my backend and I am receiving the error

`[HPM] Error occurred while proxying request matt.hearthdisplay.com:3000/api/user/my to http://localhost:8000/ [ECONNREFUSED] (https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors)`

I am not even calling `proxy` in my package.json so I am not sure why it's even attempting this? For context the API GET requests are working on my coworker's machines with the same code and I have recently moved to a new location with a different wifi router so I am not sure if this is a computer-specific problem.

`matt.hearthdisplay.com:3000/api/user/my` is my front end react app and `http://localhost:8000/` is for my backend.

What could be causing this? I am on a Macbook M1 running Mac OS Montery 12.3 below are my files that should help. I have tried everything online I have found...

API Request thats producing the error

```
 useEffect(() => {
    async function inner() {
      const response = await axiosClient.get(`/user/my`, {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
        },
      });
      if (response.status === 200) {
        setFormState({
          firstName: response.data.user.first_name,
          lastName: response.data.user.last_name,
        });
      }
    }

    if (!!token) {
      inner();
    }
  }, [token]);
```

axiosCLient.ts

```
import axios, { AxiosResponse } from "axios";
import { apiRoot } from "./variables";

const axiosClient = axios.create({
  baseURL: apiRoot,
});

// Timeout in 3 seconds by default
axiosClient.defaults.timeout = 3000;

function handle2xxResponse(response: AxiosResponse<any>): AxiosResponse<any> {
  return response;
}

axiosClient.interceptors.response.use(handle2xxResponse);

export default axiosClient;
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "webapp",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.7.1",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.6.0",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.36",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.15.4",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.1.16",
    "@fullhuman/postcss-purgecss": "^4.1.3",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.2.4",
    "@mui/material": "^5.2.4",
    "@mui/styled-engine-sc": "^5.1.0",
    "@sentry/react": "^6.16.1",
    "@sentry/tracing": "^6.16.1",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.15",
    "@types/node": "^12.0.0",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.0",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.0",
    "@types/react-lottie": "^1.2.6",
    "axios": "^0.24.0",
    "http-proxy-middleware": "^2.0.3",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.21.2",
    "react-lottie": "^1.2.3",
    "react-native-dropdown": "^0.0.6",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.0.2",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.3",
    "tailwindcss": "^2.2.19",
    "typescript": "^4.1.2",
    "web-vitals": "^1.0.1",
    "zustand": "^3.6.5"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build:tailwind": "postcss src/styles/index.tailwind.css -o src/styles/index.css",
    "watch:tailwind": "postcss -w src/styles/index.tailwind.css -o src/styles/index.css",
    "start": "run-p watch:tailwind start:react",
    "start:react": "react-scripts start",
    "prebuild": "npm run build:tailwind",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.0",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.1.5",
    "postcss": "^8.4.4",
    "postcss-cli": "^9.0.2"
  }
}
```

setUpProxy.js

```
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require("http-proxy-middleware");

module.exports = function (app) {
  app.use(
    createProxyMiddleware("/api", {
      target: "http://localhost:8000",
      changeOrigin: true,
      secure: false,
    })
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Trying add the following header in the proxy code;

```
target: "http://localhost:8000",
headers: {
        "Connection": "keep-alive"
    },
...
```

The Keep-Alive general header allows the sender to hint about how the connection may be used to set a timeout and a maximum amount of requests.

Comment: Thanks, I tried and still getting the same error...Its weird because other people running exact same app dont seem to need that...is there a browser or computer specific cash that could be the culprit?

Comment: To my knowledge, that error means there's nothing running at http://localhost:8000.  Compare the package.json with others, make sure the port on your localhost is not already in use.  Try look here for possible solutions: https://github.com/chimurai/http-proxy-middleware/issues/171

Comment: Great advice I am seeing that when I run python server.py to start my backend its starting 2 instances of it on port :8000 so I will try and solve why that is occuring.